# Debugging procedure for Hadoop Failed/Hung job

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am learning Hadoop Administration but I don't know how to start debugging if my job is taking more time than its average, or where to start the debugging if my job has failed.

I generally starts with logs in Resource Manager UI but I want to know if there is any other **process to debug as a Hadoop Admin**. I am looking for a generic approach to follow for debugging Hadoop jobs using Hortonworks Ambari Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Logs help in case you end up with failed jobs. I am assuming your jobs are successful but slow.

Best place to start debugging for slow running jobs would be to look at the Job Counters (Once you get into the MR App Master page for the Job, you can find the counters link on left panel). Look at **Hadoop Definitive Guide**'s *Chapter 8* for details on what each counter means.